# Linux C serial port reading, VTIME is not enough

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, termios

I wrote a C reading serial port application using termios.h library. Using non-canonical mode I set VMIN to 255 and VTIME to 1 . It works well, but only when messages have more than 50ms interval time. Is there any way to set VTIME to less then 0.1s? Of course I could set VTIME to 0 and VMIN to proper value, but messages are not constant size.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: According to the man page: *"VTIME is a timer of 0.1 second granularity"*. So that seems like a "No." But it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: *"Is there any way to set VTIME to less then 0.1s?"* -- No,  But from my experience (and apparently yours too), the VTIME value isn't that accurate or reliable.  This expiration timer seems faster than expected. IMO the solution is to abandon  the idea that you can use non-canonical **read()** to return a complete and aligned message packet.  Instead assume that you're getting a byte stream, and write code to find and extract the message packets.